# Using the ArcGIS 'select by location' tool in ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder

I have a model that outputs a shapefile which shows the extent of flooding. I also have a layer of buildings. I want to see which buildings are affected by different flood scenarios.

When I use Select by Location, my results look like this, which is what I want:

[image]

However, Select by Location isn't something that can be added to a model, so I'm looking for a workaround. Unfortunately, using the Clip and/or Intersection tools, I get many small artifact polygons. I was wondering how to add Select by Location to a model, or if there was some way to perform an overlap/within type of intersect rather than the default.

Comment: Are your datasets in the same coordinate system?

Comment: @BERA To clarify, Selection by Location DOES work, but it is not something that can be added to a model, and I'm looking for a workaround.

Comment: @Hornbydd Yes, they are in the same CRS

Comment: @BERA You are a lifesaver, much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Select By Location in Modelbuilder but not the one in Selection menu. Instead go to ArcToolBox - Data Management Tools - Layers and Table Views - Select Layer By Location. Or  menu Geoproccessing - Search for Tools and type Select Layer by Location